# C++ comparing two objects

Tags: c++, object, compare

I got this function:

```
bool operator==(const foo& foo1, const foo& foo2)
```

how do I compare the two objects with each other, is there a library function that allows me to doit? or do I have to physically compare each of the variables inside the objects.

EDIT:

`foo` object holds:

```
private: 
int *values;
size_t *columns; 
std::map< size_t, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> > maps;
```

Comment: Just curious, when you preferred `std::map`, `std::pair`, why didn't you opt `std::vector` instead of raw pointers?

Comment: this is a homework assignment, so im going by what my lecturer gave me.

Answer (score 5):

The semantics of the comparison function depends on your intent and in the nature and semantics of object's internals. In your case only you know what `foo` is and, therefore, only you know how to properly compare one `foo` object to another `foo` object. There's no universal one-fits-all answer to your question.

Comment: `foo` holds 3 private variables, of pointers to 3 different arrays `int *values;` `size_t *columns;` and `std::map< size_t, std::pair<size_t, unsigned int> > maps;`

Comment: @wpp: So, are `foo1` and `foo2` considered equal if their `values` pointers are equal (i.e., are both null or both point to the same `int` object), or if they point to possibly different `int` objects with the same value?  Or does `values` point to the first element of an array of `int`; if so, how many elements of the array are relevant?  And so on for `columns` and `maps`.  You'll have to decide what equality means.

Comment: @Keith sorry about my vague description, let me clarify this, both `values` pointers create two different arrays, and are considered equal, if each array they are pointing to have the same values. i.e if the elements at the addresses of each element in array are the same value, then both objects are equal

Comment: @wpp: OK well you already know part of the answer. But you have no choice, you have to take a description like you gave above and turn it into code. You're learning to be a programmer, at some you have to stop saying 'where's the library to do this' and instead start saying 'how to I write the code to do this'.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go through and compare the variables inside yourself.

That way, you define what equality is. If `foo` represents a person, you can define two `foo`s as equal by just the first name, or by first and last name, or by social security number, or whatever you want. Only you, as the writer of the class, know what it means for two of your objects to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependant on the class `foo` and what data members it has, and what a vaild equality is. Imagine you `foo` is the following:

```
class foo {
private:
    long id;
    ...
};
```

If you wanted to compare based on the `id` field:

```
bool operator==(const foo& foo1, const foo& foo2) { return foo1.id == foo2.id; }
```

They can be as simple or complicated as your needs require.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the overloaded operator you have is for a static function defined outside of the `foo` class.  Since you stated that the data members of `foo` are declared as `private`, you're going to have a tough time getting your operator to work.

If you are required to use that signature for your homework, you need to research the `friend` keyword...after all, it *is* homework, nobody's going to do it for you.

If not, consider making the operator a member of the `foo` class.  [This](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html) is a great general reference for operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator ==(const Student &first, const Student &second)
{
    return (first.rollno == second.rollno && first.str == second.str);
}

class Student
{
public:
    string str;
    int rollno;

    Student(string str1,int rollno1)
    {
        str=str1;
        rollno1=rollno;
    }
};

cout <<"is s1=s2? \n" << boolalpha << operator==(s1,s2) <<endl;
```